# Convert string to object, remove some elements then again convert it back to string

Tags: javascript, tags

How to remove all the nodes containing the Class name = "SOMECLASSNAME"?

Lets say, suppose

I have a user-defined string(str) that contains elements span under spans and having the classname = "SOMECLASSNAME". Then I have converted this string to DOM object using this:

```
html1 = $.parseHTML(str);
```

After removing the spans containing the classname = "SOMECLASSNAME", I have to convert again it to string. Please help me out for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `$.parseHTML()` then presumably you're OK with a jQuery solution, so:

```
var $temp = $("<div></div>");
$temp.append(str).find(".SOMECLASSNAME").remove();
str = $temp.html();
```